# How to bind in xaml to a textbox from a different class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I can figure out how to bind a property to a textbox in the codebehind, but with my current application I need to bind to a property from a different class. Here's a simplified version of what I have:

```
<Window x:Class="Project1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="Textbox1" Text="{Binding Class1.Class2.TextToBind, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="20"  Width="75" Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
</Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Class1 = new Class1();
        }
        public Class1 Class1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Class1:

```
namespace Project1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public Class1()
        {
            Class2 = new Class2();
        }
        public Class2 Class2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Final class:

```
namespace Project1
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public Class2()
        {
        }
        private string textToBind;
        public string TextToBind { get { return textToBind; } set { SetProperty(ref textToBind, value); } }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
        {
            if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
            {
                field = value;
                var handler = PropertyChanged;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a question? If the code example does something other than what you want it to do, please be _specific_. Explain in precise detail what that code does, and how that's different from what you want it to do. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set DataContext for your TextBox or for your Window

```
namespace Project1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Class1 = new Class1();


            Class1.Class2.TextToBind = "Test";

            this.DataContext = this;
        }
        public Class1 Class1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Also you need to inherit Class2 from INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class Class2 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Class2()
    {
    }
    private string textToBind;
    public string TextToBind { get { return textToBind; } set { SetProperty(ref textToBind, value); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void SetProperty<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I still get nothing when I do this. Do you think that Class1 needs to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged too, since a change to Class2 is a change to Class1's property?

Comment: I did not inherit Class1 from INotifyPropertyChanged and it worked for me. I will try it again in 6 hours and will share my code

Comment: @Reuben, how can I send the test project that contains my answer to  you?

Comment: I've sent it, please check

Comment: I do not see it. Note that there is an 'e' that is missing in the email address compared to my name.

Comment: gmail blocked it. Check your mail, I've sent you drive link

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bind your `textbox` to a property from a class other than the datacontext of the window, you need to set it **explicitly**

---

I tried this code and it worked

```
<Window x:Class="Project1.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

      <!-- first add namespace of your project-->    
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project1"

    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

   <!--second define your data context class as resource-->
    <Window.Resources >
        <local:Class2 x:Key="class2"></local:Class2>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="Textbox1" Text="{Binding TextToBind, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="20"  Width="75" Background="#FFE5E5E5">


           <!--third set the data context of the textbox Explicitly-->
            <TextBox.DataContext>
                <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="class2"/>
            </TextBox.DataContext>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

**Please note** : if you are going to set the property `TextToBind` programmatically and you want your UI to show the result, you have to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: After implementing these three things, I get two errors.
First is in the MainWindow.g.cs: `The type or namespace name 'Class2' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`
Second is in MainWindow.xaml: `The name "Class2" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Class2".`

Any ideas how to fix these?

Comment: 1- make sure that your    Class2 is in the root namespace ( not in folders.. or you have to change a little bit in xaml)
2- I think if you solved the first one this is gonna disappear :)

Comment: My Class2 is in a folder. I've tried changing definition for the datacontext class like this `<local:Class2 x:Key="Folder1.class2"></local:Class2>` but that doesn't work. Do you know what specific changes need to be made?

Comment: change  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project1" To 

xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project1.Folder1"  :)